# Facebook graph api: How to get all own properties

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-manager

I want get all properties in my business like this list apps in https://business.facebook.com/pub/properties

The api response has `property_name` and `property_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this api:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{business_id}/owned_apps?access_token={access_token}&fields=id,name,property_id`